# Excel creates a new row(with data from the first row) when there is a change in A

Tags: vba, excel

Amateur here - sorry if this is simple and I'm not getting it.

So in my workbook I have a timer that updates every 3 mins In A2. In B2, C2, D2, etc. I have fluctuating values from plugins, that have a very fast refresh rate.

I need a macro that will "log" the values in B2, C2 etc. as a new row, every time the value in A2 changes(with the time from the timer there also). Here is what I have so far(excluding timer macro, it works great):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Worksheet_Change Range("A2")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("B2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("C2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("D2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("E2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("F2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("G2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("H2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that when I use the plug in to put in the values for B2, C2 etc, everything goes wild and it starts creating new rows(if you want to try this for yourself, put `=RANDBETWEEN(40,80)` as one of the values - it perfectly emulates the problem I face).

Back to my question, how do I make the macro only create a new row when there is a change in A2?

Any help is welcome, thanks you for your time!

Comment: Note: You should research what `Application.EnableEvents = True` or `False` does and how many you need, where and why!

Comment: You call the change event every time there's a recalculate event, and force the target to be A2. So whenever any cell changes your code runs. I don't see why you have this code? 

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Worksheet_Change Range("A2")
End Sub

Comment: If I remove that code, it doesn't log anything. I think I have to force it to target A2? What would you suggest I use instead? @HarassedDad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this and it does what you expect it to (replace your code with the following and remove the worksheet_calculate) Also you should probably change Sheet1 to whatever your Sheet is or even to ActiveSheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Sheet1.Range("A2").Address Then 'check to see if changes happend on A2
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value 'copy the row from Row 2 to next empty row
        Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("B2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("C2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("D2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("E2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("F2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("G2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet1.Range("H2").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```